# Вывод в json немецкого языка. Какую кодировку использовать?

Tags: php, json, кодировка, iso

Не получается вывести немецкий язык в json
Если не кодировать данные json в utf-8 то на странице ничего не выводится.
Если же перекодировать данные в utf-8 то немецкие символы выводятся так KopfhГѓВ¶rer.
Как быть? как можно вывести в json немецкие символы? Какую кодировку нужно использовать для немецкого языка?
кодируется строка так

```
utf8_encode($str);
```

выводиться так

```
echo json_encode($str, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Юникод. И выводить в юникоде, а не что там у вас.

Comment: utf-8 должно нормально кодировать, возможно у вас неправильная кодировка источника символов, например неправильная кодировка выставлена в СУБД, или неправильная кодировка выставлена в файле исходника, или неправильно декодируется json. Промежуточная кодировка должна быть либо Юникод, либо чисто немецкая (по-моему 1252) либо тоже utf-8.

Comment: в файле исходнике utf-8